# Removing boilerplate for a wrapper class in kotlin

Tags: java, arraylist, kotlin, wrapper, boilerplate

I'm trying to implement a wrapper around the java's `ArrayList`. It forwards many method calls like `add`, `remove`, `removeIf`, `get` directly to the implementation `ArrayList`. This java class contains a lot of boilerplate.

```
public class JSONArray extends JSONType implements Iterable<JSONType> {

    private ArrayList<JSONType> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public JSONType get(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }
        public JSONArray add(int i, JSONType j) {
        data.add(i, j);
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(JSONType j) {
        data.add(j);
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(int i, String j) {
        data.add(i, new JSONString(j));
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(String j) {
        data.add(new JSONString(j));
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(int i, Double j) {
        data.add(i, new JSONDouble(j));
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(Double j) {
        data.add(new JSONDouble(j));
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(int i, int j) {
        return add(i, (double) j);
    }
    public JSONArray add(int j) {
        return add((double) j);
    }
    public JSONArray add(int i, Boolean j) {
        JSONBoolean b = j ? JSONBoolean.True : JSONBoolean.False;
        data.add(i, b);
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray add(Boolean j) {
        JSONBoolean b = j ? JSONBoolean.True : JSONBoolean.False;
        data.add(b);
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray addNull(int i) {
        data.add(i, JSONNull.Null);
        return this;
    }
    public JSONArray addNull() {
        data.add(JSONNull.Null);
        return this;
    }
```

Is there any way to clean up this boilerplate code in kotlin?

Comment: Show us your code. I have a hard time understanding which boilerplate it contains, unless you count `= list.remove(element)` as boilerplate.

Comment: @JBNizet I've added the code to the post.

Comment: That's not Kotlin. It's Java. Do you want to write a Kotlin class or a Java class?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes that's what I want/

Comment: What is "that". Kotlin or Java?

Comment: @JBNizet I want to know how I can remove this boilerplate if I choose to use kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, you would simply do this:

```
class JSONArray: JSONType, Iterable<JSONType> {

    private val data = mutableListOf<JSONType>();

    fun get(i: Int) = data.get(i)

    fun add(i: Int, j: JSONType) = data.add(i, j)
    fun add(j: JSONType) = data.add(j)
    // etc.
}
```

That won't make it a fluent API, but it's not a problem in Kotlin, because you can use the basic functions of the language (`with`, `apply` for example) to avoid repeating the variable again and again. For example:

```
with(jsonArray) {
    add(foo)
    add(bar)
    add(0, baz)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

ArrayList is not final. You can inherit from it and override only methods you need to change.